# Unique pointer - Why is the destructor called 3 times

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a method that returns an object by value. The method comes from a library that I have no control over. For the further handling of the object I want to continue working with a unique_ptr on this object. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Bla {
  public:
      Bla() { std::cout << "Constructor!\n"; }
      ~Bla() { std::cout << "Destructor!\n"; }
};

Bla GetBla() {
  Bla bla;
  return std::move(bla);
}

int main() {
  auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>(GetBla());
}
```

The example produces the following output:

```
Constructor!
Destructor!
Destructor!
Destructor!
```

Why is the destructor of Bla called 3 times here? Is the way I create the unique_prt correct?

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to set a breakpoint in the destructor. Then you can easily see from where the destructors are called.

Comment: Hint: `std::move` doesn't move anything. It just casts from one type to another.

Comment: Define copy and move constructors to see full picture. Also using `std::move` on `return` is a big mistake.

Comment: Don't return an object using std::move. This prevents RVO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are indeed 3 times that an instance of `Bla` is constructed.

```
Bla GetBla() {
  Bla bla;    // 1st construction
  return std::move(bla); // 2nd construction (return by copy)
}
```

Don't return by move. Just return `bla`, in most cases the copy will be elided.

```
  auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>(GetBla());  // 3rd construction - Bla copy construction
```

Note that `make_unique<Bla>` always constructs a new instance. In this case because you're passing another instance, it becomes copy-construction.

A hint that copy construction takes place is that your default constructor is invoked only once, while the destructor is invoked 3 times. That's because in the other 2 cases the implicit copy (or move) constructor is invoked (`Bla::Bla(Bla const&)`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I thought that std::move was supposed to prevent copying, but apparently it does the opposite.

Comment: @TobiS. It would be a move construction instead of a copy construction, but your object does not automatically have a move constructor, [because you defined a destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor).

Comment: Do you think `// 2nd construction (return by copy)` is not correct? The returned value will be move constructed? See this (I could be wrong): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487169/5735010.

Comment: @abhiarora see 2nd comment. There is no move constructor.

Comment: Oh Got it. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest adding copy/move ctor to the code. Remember the rule of 3 idiom.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler may even warn you that

> moving a local object in a return statement prevents copy elision.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you get the three desctructor calls from:

- The local variable `bla` from `GetBla()`
- The return value from `GetBla()` after it was used in `std::make_unique<Bla>(GetBla());`
- Obviously from the destructor of the `std::unique_ptr`

The easiest way is to let `std::make_uniqe` invoke the default constructor of `Bla`:

```
auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>(); // Calls Bla::Bla() to initalize the owned object
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Bla {
  public:
      Bla() { std::cout << "Constructor!\n"; }
      ~Bla() { std::cout << "Destructor!\n"; }
};

int main() {
  auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>();
}
```

Output

```
Constructor!
Destructor!
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to create `unique_ptr`:

```
auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>();
```

However, your code creates 3 instances of `Bla`:

1. Local object `bla` in `GetBla()` function.
2. Return value of `GetBla()`.
3. Finally, `make_unique()` creates one more instance.

NOTE:

1. In presence of user-defined destructor, the compiler does not generate move-constructor, so `GetBla()` return value is a copy of the local object `bla`.
2. Since `GetBla()` returns `move`'ed local object, [copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

To really see what's happening behind the scenes, you can either use a debugger or define [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) constructor. I have added the copy constructor in your code. Try the code given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Bla {
public:
    Bla(void) 
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor!" << std::endl;
    }
    //Bla(Bla &&)
    //{
    //    std::cout << "Move Constructors" << std::endl;
    //}
    Bla(const Bla &)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructors" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Bla(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor!" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int a = 2;
};

Bla GetBla(void) 
{
    Bla bla; // Default Constructor Called here
    return std::move(bla); // Second Construction over here
}

int main(void)
{
    auto bla = std::make_unique<Bla>(GetBla()); // Third Construction
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:**

`std::move` doesn't move anything. It just casts from `lvalue` reference to `rvalue` reference and your returned object could have been constructed via a move constructor (and [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) could be suppressed) but the compiler doesn't implicitly-declared `move` constructor [because you have defined the destructor (& I have added copy constructor in my example)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor)

Outputs:

```
Constructor! # 1
Copy Constructors # 2
Destructor! # 3
Copy Constructors # 4
Destructor! # 5
Destructor! # 6
```

See my comments below:

1. The object `bla` is constructed in function `GetBla()` via default constructor.
2. The return value of `GetBla()` function is copy-constructed from the object created in `# 1`.
3. `bla` object (constructed in #1) gets destroyed and it's destructor is called.
4. `std::make_unique<Bla>` calls `new` and then calls the appropriate constructor and it chooses the `copy` constructor.
5. The object created in #2 are destroyed.
6. Finally, the object created in #4 is destroyed.